# div modal popup not rendered correctly on IE when screen is maximized, works fine on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a div modal popup that displays fine in Chrome but in IE 11 it fails to render correctly. Interestingly it only fails to render when IE is maximized, if I shrink the window then it renders correctly.

I say it fails rendering because the modal popup does not show up in IE when maximized. However if I start clicking where the modal popup is supposed to be then IE weirdly starts painting it or rendering it.

Here is my html code with javascript/jquery:

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <input type="button" style="text-align:left;width:100%;height:100%;border:none;" class="light_button" ID="totalPointsID" runat="server" onclick="fnmodalpopup()" />
        <div id="dialogModal1" class="modal-background" style="display:none" >
            <div class="modal-content" >
                <div class="modal-header" >
                    <span class="modal-close" onclick="fnmodalclose()" >&times;</span>
                    <span>REWARDS</span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> Some paragraph </p>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input ID="buttonClose1" class="light_button" type="button" value="Close" onclick="fnmodalclose()" />
                    <input ID="buttonContinue1" class="button" style="float:right;" type="button" value="Continue to site" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            var myModal = document.getElementById('dialogModal1');

            // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
            function fnmodalpopup()
            {
                $('#dialogModal1').css('display', 'block');
                return false;
            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            function fnmodalclose()
            {
                $('#dialogModal1').css('display', 'none')
                return false;
            }

        </script>

    </ body >
</ html >
```

And this is my CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal-background {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border: 2px solid #888;
    width: 50%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.modal-header {
    background-color: #F8F6F9;
    color: #54276f;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.modal-body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* The Close Button */
.modal-close {
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.modal-close:hover,
.modal-close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

note: I have tried different combinations of display:inline-block/flex/inline-flex , etc. and I also tried different CSS positions fixed, relative, etc. and I have researched in many other sites and similar questions posted, no luck yet. thank you.

Comment: I received a suggestion to try a CSS reset (search for CSS resets, Eric Myer)  but that does not solve the problem. I would like to clarify that my html code is actually a module nested within other div blocks so resetting the CSS completely messes up customization for other modules and div blocks.

Comment: Because the modal "repaints itself" or renders correctly if the user clicks on the screen space where it is supposed to be I was hoping for a fix on the lines of something that re-paints or re-draws (I am missing the correct word here) the visible screen.

I also tried CSS position:absolute for modal-background and modal-content but that has the problem that it cuts/trims my modal popup as it is nested as a module contained within other div blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the right suggestion. 
Because my div modal popup is nested within other div blocks and modules, that may have been causing the problem. The solution is moving the div modal popup as the first child element of 
With jquery that is very easy to do:

```
$("body").prepend($('#dialogModal1'));
```